# Struts2 autogenerated dropdownlist doesn't refresh new items on the second select

Tags: struts2, jsp-tags

I have try to implement a form with two select on my form, with doubleselect tag of struts 2, where the content of the second select is conditioned from the first. So surfing the net, i have found the post : http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-sdoubleselect-example/, i have try the example suggested by the blogger, but when i choose an element from the first select, the second select did not change it's value.

So, i have debbuged it with firebug on mozilla 17.01 and the javascript autogenerated with the jsp tag doubleselect seems good, cause i have any error into the console. Debugging the code autogenerated with the struts 2 tag, s:doubleselect, i have saw that option element are removed well, but maybe the second select is not refreshed. So for example on the example, when the page is in the firse select i have .net language and in the second .sharp and .vnet, when in the first i choose java, onChange, onDebugg the function that permits to change items to the second select is trigger, the old options are deleted , and the new options are created ad inserted in the the second, but the content of the second select did not change on the page.

So on the link, i have used used the last exampe, programming language:

jsp form

```
         <form:main action="DoubleSelectAction" id="channelerForm">
                   <s:doubleselect label="Language (Java List) "
                    id= "Test1" 
                    name="language1" 
                    list="languageMap.keySet()" 
                    doubleId="secondoItem"
                    doubleName="language2" 
                    doubleList="languageMap.get(top)"   />
         </form:main>
```

Define the Action:

```
public class DoubleSelectAction extends ActionSupport{


private String language1;
private String language2;

Map languageMap;


public String getLanguage1() {
    return language1;
}

public void setLanguage1(String language1) {
    this.language1 = language1;
}

public String getLanguage2() {
    return language2;
}

public void setLanguage2(String language2) {
    this.language2 = language2;
}

public Map getLanguageMap() {
    return languageMap;
}

public void setLanguageMap(Map languageMap) {
    this.languageMap = languageMap;
}

public DoubleSelectAction(){
  languageMap =new HashMap();       

      languageMap.put("Java", 
        new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Spring", "Hibernate", "Struts 2")));
      languageMap.put(".Net", new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("VB.Net", "C#")));
      languageMap.put("JavaScript", new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("jQuery")));
}

public String execute() {
    return SUCCESS;
}

public String display() {
    return NONE;
}}
```

So i would like to know if someone has had the same problem,

thanx for yours time.

Comment: https://github.com/coding-idiot/Struts2-Examples - here's a simple doubleSelect example.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to wrapping  tag inside wrong form tag

I mean to say you might be declared this tagLib (**<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>**)

you must use the same form rather using **form:main** tag

I just giving the sample jsp which is successfully rendering .

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>


    <s:form action="DoubleSelectAction" id="channelerForm">
                   <s:doubleselect label="Language (Java List) "
                    id= "Test1" 
                    name="language1" 
                    list="languageMap.keySet()" 
                    doubleId="secondoItem"
                    doubleName="language2" 
                    doubleList="languageMap.get(top)"   />
</s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope it helps